# JavaScript to change color of header when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble with changing the color of my header from transparent to colored when scrolling.
I can't use jQuery for this, as this is a school assignment and regular JS is a requirement.

So I have this code

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');
window.onscroll = function () { 
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 200 ) {
        header.classList.add("header-colored");
        header.classList.remove("header-transparent");
    } 
    else {
        header.classList.add("header-transparent");
        header.classList.remove("header-colored");
    }
};
```

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header-colored {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header id="header-transparent">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>business</li>
    <li>technical</li>
    <li>about us</li>
    </ul>
  </header>

<header id="header-colored">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>business</li>
    <li>technical</li>
    <li>about us</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

And I'm wondering where I'm going wrong. Bear in mind I have little experience with JS, so I guess I have at least one error in the script.

I'm also not sure how to do this in the HTML file. To begin with I only had one header, but I figured I need at least two for the JS to work (transparent and colored).

Any input? :)

Edit: To be clear, what doesn't work is the header does not change color when I scroll. It's just black (the colored one is visible behind the transparent one).

Comment: To say where you might be going wrong requires us to know what exactly is going wrong, what's not working? Please, read the "*[ask]*" guidelines, and then [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, your example is a bit hosh-posh, since it just adds two `<header>`-tags, doesn't provide us with an actual scrollable page so we can see what's happening, etc.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting here. 
I figured the two `header` tags would be a bad idea. Will change it. I don't have the scrollable page right now, as I have other issues I'm trying to figure out as well. Thanks tho!

Comment: @r4tchet Please have a look at my recommendation and updated code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have done few mistakes as below.

1. I changed the header id into `header` which refers the same in the
   css and added a default class to the header 'header-transparent'
2. I changed the selector as class name `.header-colored` into the css
   which refers the id as `#header-colored` before
3. I added one more css `.header-transparent` with transparent
   background color
4. And finally, set the class with `header.className =
   'header-colored'` instead of your `header.classList.add()`

I did it with one header and commented the other.

Working sample: You should have a scrollbar to test this

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');
window.onscroll = function () { 
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 200 ) {
        header.className = 'header-colored';
    } 
    else {
        header.className = 'header-transparent';
    }
};
```

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.header-colored {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="header-transparent">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>business</li>
    <li>technical</li>
    <li>about us</li>
    </ul>
  </header>

<!--<header id="header-colored">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>business</li>
    <li>technical</li>
    <li>about us</li>
    </ul>
  </header>-->
<div>
  More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, this worked wonders. I also realized what I did wrong, so thanks for that!

Comment: Yes, I have updated it with a content to see this in action here

Comment: I also have another question, but I think it's a little too complex to ask here. I'm trying to find a way to shoot you a pm, but I doesn't seem like it's possible?

Comment: You can raise another question and post me the link here and I can have a look and answer :-)

Comment: Can't do that, as I'd have to share my whole schoolproject :( but if you could, add me on facebook at Ludvik Lund. Would really appreciate it!:)

Comment: Sure I will do and you can put your code in GitHub and share the link

Answer (score 0):

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');
window.onscroll = function () { 
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 200 ) {
        header.classList.add("header-colored");
    } 
    else {
        header.classList.add("header-transparent");
    }
};
```

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-colored {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

p {
  max-width: 10em;
  }
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>business</li>
    <li>technical</li>
    <li>about us</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
<p>1914 translation by H. Rackham

"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
1914 translation by H. Rackham

"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."</p>
```

Well, first off, you don't have anything with ID `header` - you have a `<header>` with `id="header-transparent"`- so either change `getElementById('header')` to `getElementByTagName('header')`, or change the ID in the first one to `header-transparent`.

Second, you have assigned IDs, not classes, both in the HTML and the CSS, yet you're trying to add stuff to classes. That needs to change.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I changed to `getElementByTagName`, and I also changed the IDs to classes. I now get an error that says "cannot read property 'add' of undefined at window.onscroll". Do you know what would be causing this?

Comment: See my updated answer. It's not entirely complete, but it adds the classes. I went back to using ID, btw.